# Getting error to install tensorflow federated on Colab like IndexError

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory, tensorflow-federated

I am trying to install Tensorflow Federated on Google Colab but am getting error. Surprisingly, if I open new notebook, I can install Tensorflow Federated. Can anyone please help me?

However I used `!pip install --quiet --upgrade tensorflow-federated` too.

```
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
arviz 0.15.1 requires scipy>=1.8.0, but you have scipy 1.7.3 which is incompatible.
chex 0.1.7 requires jax>=0.4.6, but you have jax 0.3.15 which is incompatible.
flax 0.6.9 requires jax>=0.4.2, but you have jax 0.3.15 which is incompatible.
google-colab 1.0.0 requires portpicker~=1.3.1, but you have portpicker 1.5.2 which is incompatible.
orbax-checkpoint 0.2.1 requires jax>=0.4.8, but you have jax 0.3.15 which is incompatible.
pymc 5.1.2 requires cachetools>=4.2.1, but you have cachetools 3.1.1 which is incompatible.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-343245986933> in <cell line: 18>()
     16 
     17 import tensorflow as tf
---> 18 import tensorflow_federated as tff
     19 
     20 import collections

10 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/attr/__init__.py in __getattr__(name)

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Hi @S M Sarwar, There could be conflict between supporting libraries of existing tensorflow version 2.12 and the latest TF federated version 0.59.0 which is causing this error. Please try again installing the TF federated by specifying the version 0.55.0 or below (using `!pip install --quiet --upgrade tensorflow-federated==0.55.0`) to support with the existing `Tensorflow version 2.12` in Google Colab. Let us know if the issue still persists.

Comment: No. I didn't find that issue anymore. Now, I am using !pip install --quiet --upgrade tensorflow-federated